# Vuejs add conditional style formatting

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a simple table rendered which i would like to add some conditional css style formatting to the cells based on the value in that cell.
e.g.

If the value of *`area1 == 'one'`* assign `td-one` css style

```
      <tr v-for="version in versions" :key="version.id">
        <td>{{version.name}}</td>
        <td>{{version.area1}}</td>
        <td>{{version.area2}}</td>
        <td>{{version.area1}}</td>
        <td>{{version.area4}}</td>
      </tr>
```

Script:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'versions-table',
  props: {
    msg: String
  },
  data () {
    return {
      versions: [
              {
                id: '1',
                name: 'Name1',
                area1: 'one',
                area2: 'one',
                area3: 'two',
                area4: 'three'
              }
           ]
        }
    }
}
```

CSS

```
<style scoped>
  table {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  td {
    padding: 5px;
  }

  .td-one {
    background-color: green;
  }

  .td-two{
    background: red;
  }

  .td-three{
    background-color: blue;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`class binding`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) as follows :

```
  <td :class="{'td-one':version.area1 == 'one'}">{{version.area1}}</td>
```

and so on

Comment: Thanks - it needed a slight adjustment, but has worked well
```<td :class="{'td-one':version.area1 == 'one'}">{{version.area1}}</td>```

Comment: you're welcome i fixed it please try to accept it it it' heplful